# laravel api : nested comment and replies

Tags: json, laravel, api, postman

I'm a laravel beginner and want to build an API with laravel 8.

I have a **nested comment and replies system** for my posts

and the relation between comments and posts are **polymorphic**

i want to show a post and comments and replies as JSON

but i don't know my query is correct or not , because  i can't understand relation between comments and replies and i just can see all comments and replies related to the post.

this is the *JSON* response in postman :

```
[
    {
        "id": 45,
        "category_id": 11,
        "user_id": 1,
        "title": "title example",
        "body": "body example",
        "video": null,
        "study_time": "8",
        "likes": null,
        "status": null,
        "tags": [],
        "remember_token": null,
        "deleted_at": null,
        "created_at": "2021-05-01T14:09:14.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2021-05-01T14:09:14.000000Z",
        "comments": [
            {
                "id": 13,
                "commentable_id": 45,
                "commentable_type": "App\\Models\\Post",
                "parent_id": null,
                "name": "sara",
                "email": "sara@gmail",
                "comment": "its good",
                "images": null,
                "like": null,
                "dislike": null,
                "status": null,
                "remember_token": null,
                "deleted_at": null,
                "created_at": "2021-05-01T14:10:14.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2021-05-01T14:10:14.000000Z"
            },
            {
                "id": 14,
                "commentable_id": 45,
                "commentable_type": "App\\Models\\Post",
                "parent_id": 13,
                "name": "john",
                "email": "john@gmail.com",
                "comment": "its not good",
                "images": null,
                "like": null,
                "dislike": null,
                "status": null,
                "remember_token": null,
                "deleted_at": null,
                "created_at": "2021-05-01T14:10:50.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2021-05-01T14:10:50.000000Z"
            },
            {
                "id": 15,
                "commentable_id": 45,
                "commentable_type": "App\\Models\\Post",
                "parent_id": 14,
                "name": "sara",
                "email": "sara@gmail.com",
                "comment": "why?",
                "images": null,
                "like": null,
                "dislike": null,
                "status": null,
                "remember_token": null,
                "deleted_at": null,
                "created_at": "2021-05-01T14:11:12.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2021-05-01T14:11:12.000000Z"
            }
        ],

    }
]
```

as you see , the replies aren't in array and it's not clear which is a replay and which is a comment

so this is my **`PostDetailsController`**  :

```
class PostDetailsController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * Disply post and comments with replies
    **/
    public function showPost($id){

        $postFind = Post::find($id);
        if(is_null($postFind)){
            return response()->json('not found' , 404);
        }

        $post = Post::with('comments')->find($id);

        return response()->json([$post] , 200);

    }
```

**about comments :**

`comments table` :

```
chema::create('comments', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();

            $table->integer('commentable_id');
            $table->string('commentable_type');

            $table->unsignedBigInteger('parent_id')->nullable(); //nullable for comments , with value for replies
            $table->string('name' , 45);
            $table->string('email');
            $table->longText('comment');
            $table->foreign('parent_id')->references('id')->on('comments')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->softDeletes();
            $table->timestamp('created_at')->default(DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));
            $table->timestamp('updated_at')->default(DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));
        });
    }
```

so if `parent_id` is `NULL` it's a comment and if has values ( id of parent comments ) it's a reply. (and reply of reply has previous reply id as parent_id )

and the models :

`Post` :

```
class Post extends Model
{

    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id' ,
        'category_id' ,
        'title' ,
        'body' ,
        'study_time',
        'status',
        'tags',
    ];


    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Comment::class, 'commentable' );
    }

}
```

`Comment` :

```
class Comment extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
       'parent_id' ,  'name' , 'email' , 'comment' , 'status' , 'images'
    ];

    use HasFactory;

   public function commentable(){

       return $this->morphTo();

   }

   public function replies()
   {
       return $this->hasMany(Comment::class, 'parent_id');
   }

}
```

so can you please tell me is my query wrong?

and what should i do for show replies in an array ?

**EDIT**

i changed my code to this :

```
class PostDetailsController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * Disply post and comments with replies
    **/
    public function showPost($id){

        $postFind = Post::find($id);
        if(is_null($postFind)){
            return response()->json('not found' , 404);
        }

        $post = Post::with('comments.replies')->find($id);

        return response()->json([$post] , 200);

    }
```

and the response is :

```
[
    {
        "id": 45,
        "category_id": 11,
        "user_id": 1,
        "title": "title example",
        "body": "body example",
        "video": null,
        "study_time": "8",
        "likes": null,
        "status": null,
        "tags": [],
        "remember_token": null,
        "deleted_at": null,
        "created_at": "2021-05-01T14:09:14.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2021-05-01T14:09:14.000000Z",
        "comments": [
            {
                "id": 13,
                "commentable_id": 45,
                "commentable_type": "App\\Models\\Post",
                "parent_id": null,
                "name": "sara",
                "email": "sara@gmail",
                "comment": "its good",
                "images": null,
                "like": null,
                "dislike": null,
                "status": null,
                "remember_token": null,
                "deleted_at": null,
                "created_at": "2021-05-01T14:10:14.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2021-05-01T14:10:14.000000Z",
                "replies": [
                    {
                        "id": 14,
                        "commentable_id": 45,
                        "commentable_type": "App\\Models\\Post",
                        "parent_id": 13,
                        "name": "john",
                        "email": "john@gmail.com",
                        "comment": "its not good",
                        "images": null,
                        "like": null,
                        "dislike": null,
                        "status": null,
                        "remember_token": null,
                        "deleted_at": null,
                        "created_at": "2021-05-01T14:10:50.000000Z",
                        "updated_at": "2021-05-01T14:10:50.000000Z"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 14,
                "commentable_id": 45,
                "commentable_type": "App\\Models\\Post",
                "parent_id": 13,
                "name": "john",
                "email": "john@gmail.com",
                "comment": "its not good",
                "images": null,
                "like": null,
                "dislike": null,
                "status": null,
                "remember_token": null,
                "deleted_at": null,
                "created_at": "2021-05-01T14:10:50.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2021-05-01T14:10:50.000000Z",
                "replies": [
                    {
                        "id": 15,
                        "commentable_id": 45,
                        "commentable_type": "App\\Models\\Post",
                        "parent_id": 14,
                        "name": "sara",
                        "email": "sara@gmail.com",
                        "comment": "why?",
                        "images": null,
                        "like": null,
                        "dislike": null,
                        "status": null,
                        "remember_token": null,
                        "deleted_at": null,
                        "created_at": "2021-05-01T14:11:12.000000Z",
                        "updated_at": "2021-05-01T14:11:12.000000Z"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 15,
                "commentable_id": 45,
                "commentable_type": "App\\Models\\Post",
                "parent_id": 14,
                "name": "sara",
                "email": "sara@gmail.com",
                "comment": "why?",
                "images": null,
                "like": null,
                "dislike": null,
                "status": null,
                "remember_token": null,
                "deleted_at": null,
                "created_at": "2021-05-01T14:11:12.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2021-05-01T14:11:12.000000Z",
                "replies": []
            }
        ],

    }
]
```

so i can see the replies of every comment or reply in the response , but as you see the replies are repeated and the last reply that has no reply ,has `"replies[]"`

What should I do to not show the replay again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So a couple things here that you could do, firstly your replies have the commentable_type and commentable_id whereas these should probably be nullable since when looking at replies you only really need to know its parent and not the post as you can get this through the parent.

This then allows your `$post->comments` relationship to not return replies to comments.

Next you can use dot notation to add replies to your comments.

```
$post = Post::with('comments.replies')->find($id);
```

This would then return something like this

```
    [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "Title",
            "body": "Body",
            "created_at": "2021-05-01T11:34:27.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2021-05-01T11:34:28.000000Z",
            "comments": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "post_id": 1,
                    "parent_id": null,
                    "body": "No Replies",
                    "created_at": "2021-05-01T11:34:41.000000Z",
                    "updated_at": "2021-05-01T11:34:43.000000Z",
                    "replies": []
                },    
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "post_id": 1,
                    "parent_id": null,
                    "body": "One Reply",
                    "created_at": "2021-05-01T11:35:18.000000Z",
                    "updated_at": "2021-05-01T11:35:19.000000Z",
                    "replies": [
                        {
                            "id": 3,
                            "post_id": null,
                            "parent_id": 2,
                            "body": "Reply",
                            "created_at": "2021-05-01T11:35:29.000000Z",
                            "updated_at": "2021-05-01T11:35:32.000000Z"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

Comment: thank you and i edited my code and question .. can you please check my question again?

Comment: So from what I can see with your relationships a better idea would be to remove the parent id completely from a comment. As you have commentable_id and commentable_type a reply is technically a comment of a comment. So the commentable_id and commentable_type of a reply would be its parent comment. And then change the replies relationship as such. Give this relationship a go, and if you have an issues comments again on here and I will take a look.